# Python numpy interpolation gives wrong output

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I have an input and output array. I have given below the plot. I want to interpolate value at x=0. I was expecting something like  around 16.7 but instead giving 17.4881, peak value. What could be wrong.

Data :

[image]

My code:

```
xdata = [0.101,-0.008,-0.111,-0.209,-0.303]
ydata = [16.5241,16.7987,17.0499,17.2793,17.4885]
xp = np.interp(0,xdata,ydata)
print(xp)
```

Present output:

```
  17.4885
```

Expected output:

```
16.7 # around from plot
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [interp function documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html), it says that

> The x-coordinates of the data points, must be increasing if argument period is not specified. Otherwise, xp is internally sorted after normalizing the periodic boundaries with xp = xp % period.

But your xdata is in descending order, so you need to reverse order in `xdata` and `ydata`

```
import numpy as np
xdata = [0.101,-0.008,-0.111,-0.209,-0.303][::-1]
ydata = [16.5241,16.7987,17.0499,17.2793,17.4885][::-1]
xp = np.interp(0,xdata,ydata)
print(xp)
# 16.778545871559633
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I appreciate for the elegant answer.